# Does SharePoint Online have plugin tools for SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) or is there an API for accessing and writing reports?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, reporting-services, api

I've been looking around for a while and haven't found anything yet. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, SSRS is only supported in on-premises installations of SharePoint Server, it is not support in SharePoint Online.

Reference:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-show-ssrs-reports-in-sharepoint-online/1d94a167-6ac7-49f3-9201-c6d04df4ff9a?auth=1